# Vector initialized by enum

Tags: c++, vector, enums

The following code doesn't build.

```
struct some_struct {
    some_struct() {
      ... do something here to specify size of v; how ??
    }
    enum {
       ZERO,
       ONE,
       TWO
    };

    static std::vector<std::string> v(TWO);
};
```

Appreciate any ideas.. nothing seems to suggest this is illegal use.

Typo: Fixed the vector syntax and correction: I have only tested on 2005/2008, not 2010. The error message for those who asked:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'TWO'
```

Further edit:

It looks like the compiler thinks `v` is a function that returns type `std::vector<std::string>`; all of this is inside a `struct` (I have now further corrected my post to clarify this some more). Perhaps I need to leave out the size argument which it confuses with a type and declare the size somewhere in the constructor? I meant for this vector to be a static data member of the struct. How do I get the compiler to understand this?

NOTE: On Linux I tested it on a standalone code resembling what I had up originally (without the struct)... so maybe it wouldn't compile on Linux with this correction. So I removed the comment that it built OK on Linux. Apologies.

Comment: What is the error message?  This compiles fine on VS2010, once you fix the obvious error (no type specified for the vector).

Comment: I doubt it compiles on any platform or compiler. You need to specify a type for a vector.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, at first I thought it might be the most vexing parse, but trying it showed that you are correct: http://ideone.com/ccTWv

Comment: Even after fixing up the obvious namespace errors, the lack of type still breaks it: http://ideone.com/QfPeK

Comment: Bah! That was a typo, guys. Fixed. Actual code didn't have the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize the class member in the class declaration. You need to instantiate it outside:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct some_struct {
    some_struct() {
    }
    enum {
       ZERO,
       ONE,
       TWO
    };

    static std::vector<std::string> v;
};

std::vector<std::string>
some_struct::v = std::vector<std::string>(TWO);

int main() {}
```

Comment: It should be using the standard constructor "explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );". Perhaps Visual C++ doesn't have that one?

Comment: Hmm.. I made a lot of corrections/clarifications to my original post (which admittedly was devoid of details). Kindly take another look.

Comment: Or maybe Visual C++ won't auto-convert an enum value to a size_type. std::vector<int>::size_type is "implementation defined", so maybe it's legitimate to not do the conversion.

Comment: Thanks @moooeeeep: You might've nailed it. WTF would C++ make this so complicated? I tried something close, but didn't try the assignment operator on the vector (v) like you did.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: All of the following is invalidated by OP's corrections to the original question.**

It all depends on where you got the definition of `vector` from. If somewhere you've included a standard C++ #include file which defines the `vector<>` template, (or, more recently, the `std::vector<>` template), then you'll get errors because it's defined as a template but no type is provided. It expects something like:

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

If you haven't included the standard file somewhere along the way, it's getting the definition of vector from somewhere else, and Lord only knows what sort of constructor arguments it expects.

Anyway, vector as a class is non-standard, and it's not surprising if the declarations and implementations differ (or are absent) from one environment to another.

Comment: `std::vector` most certainly is in the standard. The rest of the answer is also wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is. Did I suggest differently somewhere?

Comment: The last bit, starting with "anyway, vector as a class is non-standard..." `std::vector` is always a class.

Comment: Ah. I meant "class" in the sense of "not a template". You are of course correct, in that vector<int> is a class, and vector<string> is a class, etc. I guess my point is that it's clearly not referencing the standard vector, so there's no way to tell what the problem is.

Comment: While there are a variety of problems with the snippet as given, names resolving to some other vector class is *not* suggested by the question in any way.

Comment: Thanks @A.L.Flanagan: Made a lot more corrections.. kindly take another look.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize a vector in the header like that. Since it's static you do it in the source file, at the place it's declared:

```
std::vector<std::string> some_struct::v(TWO);
```

If it weren't static you would do it in the class constructor's initialization list.

Comment: Who said I did it in the header? This is in the implementation (CPP). The struct is a private member of another class.

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo, usually class declarations go in a header so I just assumed. My point is that the static `v` member must be declared in the class declaration then defined again somewhere outside of the class declaration.